# (The) people he might hurt. The definite article or no article at all?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-article, semantics

From my quick Google search, it seems like such constructions can be used both with the article and without it.

So, how does the article change meaning in the following sentences:

*He showed little concern **for people** he might hurt*.

*He showed little concern **for the people** he might hurt*.

What is the difference between the two? Does the clause (he might hurt) have a descriptive meaning in the first sentence and a limiting meaning in the second? And is there actually a difference in how these sentences will be perceived by native speakers? How to choose the correct article in sentences like these?

Comment: The version with _the_ sounds more natural t me but I have no idea what the rule is here.

Comment: @PeterJennings , yes it does! Thank you!